# MUI v5 - Different classes are being applied on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've recently migrated from Mui v4 to v5 and I've been experiencing a weird behaviour with checkboxes. When comparing the old and new versions in the DOM it seems to me that a few additional classes are being applied with v5 and that the extra span with the className `MuiIconButton-label` is not being applied anymore, this makes my lists look a bit odd as checkboxes won't pick up the same styling anymore. I know its been a shift from jss to emotion but everything else seems to behave as usual.

I've migrated with the help of the provided codemods in the migration docs [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/).

Old DOM:

```html
<span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss10 MuiCheckbox-root
      MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary Checkbox jss11 Mui-checked --checked 
      MuiIconButton-colorSecondary" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
        <input class="jss13" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="" checked="">
        <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
    </span>
</span>
```

DOM after migrating to V5:

```html
<span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary 
      PrivateSwitchBase-root MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiCheckbox-root 
      MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary Checkbox css-1k6mikw-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiCheckbox-root">
    <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false">
    <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" font-size="medium"></svg>
</span>
```

For first, I thought it could be an issue with the order in which styling is being injected, so I tried using the `StyledEngineProvider` component like this:

```js
return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <LocaleUtils.LocaleProvider>
          <ErrorBoundary fatal={true} resetKey={resetKey}>
            {(topLevelError: Error | null) =>
              topLevelError ? (
                <FatalError error={topLevelError} />
              ) : (
                React.createElement(routerManager.component, {
                  children: (routes: any) => <RouterContent renderId={renderId} routes={routes} />,
                } as any)
              )
            }
          </ErrorBoundary>
        </LocaleUtils.LocaleProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
```

But it didn't make a difference.

When switching the checkbox component back to the v4 version (importing from material-ui/core) it fixes the issue.

My checkbox.tsx:

```js
import "./Checkbox.scss";

import React, { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { IconLine, IconTick } from "../../../assets";
import { Checkbox }  from "@mui/material";

import * as Utils from "../../../lib/util/Utils";

export interface CheckboxProps {
  id?: string;
  value?: string | boolean;
  checked?: boolean;
  indeterminate?: boolean;
  defaultValue?: boolean;
  className?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  onChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, checked: boolean, id?: string) => void;
  size?: "small" | "medium";
}

const CustomCheckbox = (props: CheckboxProps) => {
  const { id, value, checked, size, onChange, disabled, className, defaultValue, indeterminate } = props;

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, checked: boolean) => {
      if (onChange) {
        onChange(event, checked, id);
      }
    },
    [id, onChange],
  );

  const isChecked = useMemo(() => {
    if (checked !== undefined) {
      return checked;
    }

    return Boolean(value);
  }, [value, checked]);

  return (
    <Checkbox
      disabled={disabled}
      onClick={Utils.stopPropagation}
      size={size}
      disableRipple={true}
      icon={<IconTick />}
      checkedIcon={<IconTick />}
      indeterminateIcon={<IconLine />}
      indeterminate={indeterminate}
      className={clsx("Checkbox", className)}
      classes={{
        checked: "--checked",
        indeterminate: "--indeterminate",
        disabled: "--disabled",
      }}
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={value}
      checked={isChecked}
      defaultChecked={defaultValue}
      tabIndex={0}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomCheckbox;
```

Checkbox scss:

```css
@import "../../../stylesheet/toolkit";

@mixin checkbox-color($color) {
  color: $color !important;

  &.--checked,
  &.--indeterminate {
    .MuiIconButton-label {
      border-color: $color;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px transparentize($color, 0.7);
    }
  }
}

.Checkbox.MuiCheckbox-root {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  @include checkbox-color($goldenrod);

  &:hover {
    background: transparent;
  }

  @each $color, $value in $placeholders-colors {
    &.--col-#{$color} {
      @include checkbox-color($value);
    }
  }

  @each $color, $value in $colors {
    &.--col-#{$color} {
      @include checkbox-color($value);
    }
  }

  .MuiIconButton-label {
    border: 1px solid $grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
  }

  &.--checked {
    svg {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }

  &.--disabled {
    @include checkbox-color($grey);

    .MuiIconButton-label {
      border-style: dashed;
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  }
}

.Checkbox {
  svg {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the migration guide here: https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#update-css-class-names (also a related change to `Button` [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#remove-span-and-label)).

> ### Checkbox
>
> #### Update CSS class names
>
> The component doesn't have `.MuiIconButton-root` and `.MuiIconButton-label` class names anymore.
>
> Target `.MuiButtonBase-root` instead.

It isn't just the `MuiIconButton-label` CSS class that is missing, they removed the inner `span` entirely because it is no longer necessary for applying the default styles. You will need to rework those CSS customizations for the new (simpler) html structure. In your example, this would mean flattening the `.MuiIconButton-label {` CSS rules to apply those styles to the parent element instead, but without trying it out, I'm not sure how much additional adjustment to the CSS may be necessary.

Comment: yep just found that as well yesterday, managed to fix it by flattening the css styles as mentioned here. :) Thanks